# gstreamer: What is the canonical way to send arbitrary data "with" a media (audio) stream?

Tags: tcp, udp, metadata, gstreamer

I'm using gstreamer [my 1st gstreamer project] to send audio from one device to another likely via udpsrc and udpsink.  I also want to occasionally send a small amount of arbitrary [probably text] data in the same direction (e.g., text for the receiving device to display on its screen, a command to tell the receiving device to do something, etc.).

What's the best way to do this? Is there a canonical inband way to mux such metadata in with the audio stream on the sending end, then demux it back out on the receiving end? Or should I just use a separate out-of-band tcpserversrc and tcpclientsink path and have the sender write the commands into that pipeline and the receiver read them out?

Thanks!

...R

Comment: The first questions really is: does the transport protocol support sending of arbitrary data? Then the next question would be how to do it in gstreamer. I guess there are several hacks possible like sending something inside private codec bitsreams etc..

Comment: I was hoping there was something obvious. I haven't picked an audio transport protocol yet, but I'll see if any of them support real-time metadata.

I might have in any event answered my own question without actually answering it: I just about have to use UDP for the audio, but I don't want to miss the commands, so they'll just about have to be TCP. That might more or less rule out doing it in one stream as embedded metadata, an event, or anything else.